# Node.js express get everything after /

Tags: node.js, express

Basically, I'm trying to make a URL shortener. So you input a URL and you get a shortened version. So I do `example.com/generate/InsertUrlHere`. However, if I do something like `example.com/generate/InsertUrl/Here` it doesn't work.

Currently, I have

```js
app.get('/generate/:string', async (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params.string)  
})
```

Now I know that the above code is only taking 1 input, but in a URL I can have anywhere from just plain old `google.com` to something like `google.com/1/2/3/4/5/6/7`.

So is there any other way to do it other than

```js
app.get('/generate/:string/:string2', async (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params.string+'/'req.params.string2)  
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.get('/generate/:urlToShorten(*)', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    console.log(req.params.urlToShorten);
  });
```

when calling https://localhost:3000/generate/https://google.com

`req.originalUrl`: `/generate/https://google.com`

`urlToShorten`: `https://google.com`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you send an encoded URL so that there won't be an occurrence of `/` in it which causes the issue in your endpoint detection.
Use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode it so it would replace certain characters by escape characters and then decode it for use using [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: Well you should encode the URL from wherever the API is being called(eg Frontend) and decode it inside the api handler so that you can get back the original url to be shortened.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in order to get many strings as you like something like

```
Route: /generate/:strings(*)
Path: /generate/string1/string2/string3/string4
Key: strings, Value: string1/string2/string3/string4
```

Then you can use "/" as a delimiter in order to get each string in an array

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz Doesn't this cause issue if OP has another API endpoint like `/generate/:strings(*)/validate` or something?